# What does 'Ex:' in Google Scholar results signify?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Any Google Scholar gurus out there?

When I run a search in GS, in this case for the term 'webometrics' for the year 1988, the results all contain the following in parenthesis...

(Ex: webometrics)

My assumption that this means this particular result excludes the term 'webometrics' - which confuses me a whole lot as that is the only term I am searching for so I cannot understand why that result would be shown.

Is that assumption correct?

(As an aside, the term webometrics was first coined in 1997 so any reference before then is pretty much guaranteed to be an erroneous result!)

Comment: Google Scholar seems to be picking up on something somewhere in the archive websites where they say that they use Google Analytics to analyse webometrics. In this case, "Ex" seems to mean "For example", and isn't specific to Google Scholar.

Comment: if they had only used the latin, no one would be confused :-)  (e.g., this way)